# Position ggplot title at the top right of the plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using the excellent `theme_minimal()` found in ggplot0.9.3 which has a white background. I would like to place the title of my plots in a custom location at the top right corner of the plot. In the following example I know the `x` and `y` values, but I am wondering if there is a way to pass `xmax` and `ymax` values to ensure text placement in the top-right. Ideally, the text would be right justified.

```
#example plot
p <- qplot(mpg, wt, data = mtcars, colour = cyl)
p +  annotate("text", x = 30, y = 5, label = "Custom Title")

#what I would like
p + annotate("text", y= ymax, x =xmax_or_RightJustified)
```

Comment: A priori, I don't think there is a simple way to get the text flush into a corner. The safest approach would be to use max(x) and max(y) from the data to help you position it. One problem is that there is a default 4% expansion of the x- and y-scales as padding - what if you change it inside a plot call? You can get the equivalent of the corner coordinates with, for example, `u <- ggplot_build(p)`, extracting `u$panel$ranges[[1]]$y.range[2]` and u$panel$ranges[[1]]$x.range[2], but that's an a posteriori calculation, which I don't think you want. Is this supposed to go in a theme function?

Comment: The answer to this question lies withing `ggplot2` documentation. Just do `?geom_text` -- it explains positioning in great details.     Somehow `annotate` does not tell you that it passes all parameters to the `geom_text` (or `geom_label`), but that's what it essentially does.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use functions `max()` and `min()` inside `annotate()`, and then add `hjust=1` to ensure that text is placed inside plot (justified).

```
p + annotate("text", y= max(mtcars$wt), x =max(mtcars$mpg),label="Custom Title",hjust=1)
```

Answer (score 54):

You can do

```
p + annotate("text",  x=Inf, y = Inf, label = "Some text", vjust=1, hjust=1)
```