# How to adjust title position in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is the code:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(grid)
# pdf("a.pdf")
png('a.png')
a <- qplot(date, unemploy, data = economics, geom = "line") + opts(title='A')
b <- qplot(uempmed, unemploy, data = economics) + geom_smooth(se = F) + opts(title='B')
c <- qplot(uempmed, unemploy, data = economics, geom="path") + opts(title='C')
grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(2, 2)))
vplayout <- function(x, y) viewport(layout.pos.row = x, layout.pos.col = y)
print(a, vp = vplayout(1, 1:2))
print(b, vp = vplayout(2, 1))
print(c, vp = vplayout(2, 2))
dev.off()
```

And result:

[image]

While here is what I would like to have, i.e. to position titles near the top of y-axis:

[image]

Answer (score 28, accepted):

What you are looking for is `theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0))`. For example, using the latest version of ggplot2 and `theme` instead of `opts` we have

```
a <- qplot(date, unemploy, data = economics, geom = "line") + ggtitle("A") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0))
```

Alternatively, staying with `opts`

```
a <- qplot(date, unemploy, data = economics, geom = "line") + 
  opts(title = "A", plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0))
```

[image]

Comment: Though it looks like they haven't updated ggplot2 in a while so maybe use `opts` instead of `theme`

Comment: @Julius How would I go about adjusting  the title so that it is within the plot? I tried 'vjust' but it doesn't work  in combination with 'hjust'. I'm looking to move the title to the upper right hand corner within the plot.

Comment: @Meli, I don't think there is a similar solution to your problem; you should consider inserting the title to the plot simply as a text, as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14928711/position-ggplot-title-at-the-top-right-of-the-plot