# Left-adjust title in ggplot2, or absolute position for ggtitle

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to left align the title in a plot like this

```
ggplot(data = economics, aes(x = date, y = unemploy)) +
 geom_line() +
 ggtitle("Unemployment in USA between 1967 and 2007") +
 xlab("") +
 ylab("Unemployed [thousands]")
```

[image: basic ggplot2 plot]

**First attempt**

```
ggplot(data = economics, aes(x = date, y = unemploy)) + geom_line() +
 ggtitle("Unemployment in USA for some years") +
 xlab("") +
 ylab("Unemployed [thousands]") +
 theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = -0.45, vjust=2.12)))
```

[image]

Yay success! But wait... there's more... now I want to change the title to something else.

```
ggplot(data = economics, aes(x = date, y = unemploy)) +
 geom_line() +
 ggtitle("Unemployment in USA between 1967 and 2007") +
 xlab("") +
 ylab("Unemployed [thousands]") +
 theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = -0.45, vjust=2.12))
```

[image: new title]

So now I need to adjust hjust... :(

**The question**

How can I make the title left justified (a couple of pixels left of the y axis label or so) over and over again without messing with the hjust value? Or what is the relationship between hjust and the length of the string?

I have tried to annotate manually according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22512115/put-y-axis-title-in-top-left-corner-of-graph), but then I got only the title, and nothing else for some reason - and an error.

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to adjust title position in ggplot2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19621512/how-to-adjust-title-position-in-ggplot2)

Comment: @user3710546 - these two questions are NOT duplicates - this question is asking about the left border - the other question just wants a left justify.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Until someone comes up with a better solution, one way would be something like

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
p <- ggplot(data = economics, aes(x = date, y = unemploy)) +
    geom_line() +
    labs(x = NULL, y = "Unemployed [thousands]", title = NULL)

title.grob <- textGrob(
    label = "Unemployment in USA for some years",
    x = unit(0, "lines"), 
    y = unit(0, "lines"),
    hjust = 0, vjust = 0,
    gp = gpar(fontsize = 16))

p1 <- arrangeGrob(p, top = title.grob)
grid.draw(p1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Very nice! If you had not said "until someone comes up with a better solution" I might have accepted this right off the bat. :) Thanks for the quick reply too!

Comment: @konvas How would I go moving the title within the plot so that it's in the upper right hand corner? The 'hjust' works but not the 'vjust' part for me. Any suggestions are appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Would you count [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47625672/4975218) as a better solution?

Comment: @ClausWilke how? it's exactly the same idea with IMO unnecessary new names ("ggdraw", "draw_text"). Furthermore, wrapping the whole thing into an invisible ggplot2 just to add one annotation seems overkill and inefficient in this case.

Comment: @babtiste Leaving aside whether this is a good approach here, I'd like to provide a defense for the `draw_*` functions. They are wrappers around `geom_*` that (i) don't require data frames as input; (ii) don't do aesthetic mapping; (iii) don't inherit aesthetic mapping. They're useful for quick one-off annotations. You could do the same thing with geoms but will usually require at least twice as much code.

Comment: And as to `ggdraw`, I've found it useful to be able to place annotations on a global coordinate system that spans the entire plot area. This is easy in base R but can't be done in ggplot2. You could do this with grid, but I like the convenience of being able to use all ggplot2 features in this global coordinate system.

Answer (score 65):

This question refers to this github tidyverse/ggplot2 solved issue: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3252

And it is implemented in ggplot2 (development version): https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/15263f7580d6b5100989f7c1da5d2f5255e480f9/NEWS.md

> Themes have gained two new parameters, plot.title.position and plot.caption.position, that can be used to customize how plot title/subtitle and plot caption are positioned relative to the overall plot (@clauswilke, #3252).

To follow your example as a reprex:

```r
# First install the development version from GitHub:
#install.packages("devtools") #If required
#devtools::install_github("tidyverse/ggplot2")

library(ggplot2)
packageVersion("ggplot2")
#> [1] '3.2.1.9000'

ggplot(data = economics, aes(x = date, y = unemploy)) + 
  geom_line() +
  labs(x=NULL,
       y="Unemployed [thousands]",
       title = "Unemployment in USA for some years",
       subtitle = "A subtitle possibly",
       caption  = "NOTE: Maybe a caption too in italics.") +
  theme(plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0, face= "italic"), #Default is hjust=1
        plot.title.position = "plot", #NEW parameter. Apply for subtitle too.
        plot.caption.position =  "plot") #NEW parameter
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-09-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 16):

Since the release of ggplot 3.3.0 you can also use `plot.title.position = "plot"` to position the title and `plot.caption.position = "plot` subtitle at the left side of the full plot.

```
ggplot(data = economics, aes(x = date, y = unemploy)) +
    geom_line() +
    ggtitle("Unemployment in USA between 1967 and 2007") +
    xlab("") +
    ylab("Unemployed [thousands]") +
    theme(plot.title.position = "plot")
```

[image]

Comment: https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/03/ggplot2-3-3-0/#grab-bag

Answer (score 14):

You can manually adjust the layout of the `ggplot` output.  First, we set up the basic plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(data = economics, aes(x = date, y = unemploy)) +
 geom_line() +
 labs(title = "Unemployment in USA between 1967 and 2007", 
      x = NULL, y = "Unemployed [thousands]")
```

We can now convert the `ggplot` object into a `gtable` object, and inspect the layout of the elements in the plot. Notice that the `title` is in the fourth column of the grid, the same column as the main panel.

```
g <- ggplotGrob(p)
g$layout
#    t l  b r  z clip       name
# 17 1 1 10 7  0   on background
# 1  5 3  5 3  5  off     spacer
# 2  6 3  6 3  7  off     axis-l
# 3  7 3  7 3  3  off     spacer
# 4  5 4  5 4  6  off     axis-t
# 5  6 4  6 4  1   on      panel
# 6  7 4  7 4  9  off     axis-b
# 7  5 5  5 5  4  off     spacer
# 8  6 5  6 5  8  off     axis-r
# 9  7 5  7 5  2  off     spacer
# 10 4 4  4 4 10  off     xlab-t
# 11 8 4  8 4 11  off     xlab-b
# 12 6 2  6 2 12  off     ylab-l
# 13 6 6  6 6 13  off     ylab-r
# 14 3 4  3 4 14  off   subtitle
# 15 2 4  2 4 15  off      title
# 16 9 4  9 4 16  off    caption
```

To align the `title` with the left edge of the plot, we can change the `l` value to 1.

```
g$layout$l[g$layout$name == "title"] <- 1
```

Draw the modified grid:

```
grid::grid.draw(g)
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: this is such a nice solution. How can I put that in my graph plotting routine for every graph?

Comment: How could one save this new "last" and correct plot? @Weihuang Wong

Comment: @canIchangethis See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29708821/how-to-save-a-grid-plot-in-r.

Comment: Thank you, did figure it out myself after the comment and forgot to delete! Thanks for pointing me to the right spot anyways!

Answer (score 8):

I wrote the `ggdraw()` layer in `cowplot` specifically so that I could make annotations easily anywhere on a plot. It sets up a coordinate system that covers the entire plot area, not just the plot panel, and runs from 0 to 1 in both the x and y direction. Using this approach, it is easy to place your title wherever you want.

```
library(cowplot)
theme_set(theme_gray()) # revert to ggplot2 default theme

p <- ggplot(data = economics, aes(x = date, y = unemploy)) +
  geom_line() +
  ggtitle("") + # make space for title on the plot
  xlab("") +
  ylab("Unemployed [thousands]")

ggdraw(p) + draw_text("Unemployment in USA between 1967 and 2007", 
                      x = 0.01, y = 0.98, hjust = 0, vjust = 1,
                      size = 12)  # default font size is 14, 
                                  # which is too big for theme_gray()
```

[image]

Comment: Very happy to use cowplot for this solution!! ;)

Comment: Though it only works in the Plots section of R studio. If I try to "Zoom" it or save it, the draws loose their alignement. why?

Answer (score 5):

Another way to do this is to utilize `theme()`. Use the `labs` function to label all your titles `x =` for x axis, `y =` for y axis, `title =` for plot title, `fill =` or `colour =` if you have a legend you want to put a title. Inside `theme()` is `hjust = 0`, this will left justify the plot title to the left. You can delete `hjust = 0` and the plot title will be centered align.

```
labs(x = 'Sex', y = 'Age Mean', title = 'Suicide 2003-2013 Age Mean by Sex') +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(family = 'Helvetica', 
                              color = '#666666', 
                              face = 'bold', 
                              size = 18, 
                              hjust = 0))
```

Comment: he is trying to align with the left border not left axis