# How to save a grid plot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a grid plot object g.

```
class(g)
"gtable" "grob"   "gDesc"
```

I can use grid.draw(g) to draw the plot. However, I cannot figure out a way to save the plot to a pdf file.

I tried:

```
ggsave(g, file="plot.png")
```

But apparently ggsave doesn't work on such an object.

Here is an example from the ?grid.draw help page:

```
grid.newpage()
## Create a graphical object, but don't draw it
l <- linesGrob()
## Draw it
grid.draw(l)
```

Drawing works well, but saving/printing causes the problem.

Any workaround on this? Thanks!

Comment: Try `png("myfine.png"); print(g); dev.off()`. it would really help to have a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). `ggsave` is for `ggplot2` objects which have a class of `gg` or `ggplot`. The classes you list above are for lower-level `grid` objects. (ggplot is built on grid, but they are not the same thing)

Comment: Thanks! But it doesn't seem to work though. The simplest example is from the ?grid.draw help page:     grid.newpage();    l <- linesGrob();   grid.draw(l)

Comment: From the example you posted, which object has class "gtable"? Are you refering to `l`? `png("myfile.png"); plot(l); dev.off()` seems to work just fine for me. I don't understand what isn't working for you.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Yes this seems to work! I first tried print(l) so that doesn't work.

Comment: Ah, sorry, got my plot()s and print()s  mixed up.

Comment: Hello. Is it possible to save this new created png. without the standard grid of the plots. Because I want to maintain the exact same theme of the grid.draw() result in my case but when using your code, the png. saves with an "extra" grid layer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is what MrFlick answered, but for PDFs (what you asked for in your question).

```
## Initiate writing to PDF file
pdf("path/to/file/PDFofG.pdf", height = 11, width = 8.5, paper = "letter")

## Create a graphical object g here
g # print it

## Stop writing to the PDF file
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 7):

It may be worth adding that updated `ggsave` version facilites the desired export.

## Packages

```
# Load
lapply(c("ggplot2",
         "gridExtra"), 
       require, 
       character.only = TRUE)
sessionInfo()

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] gridExtra_2.2.1 ggplot2_2.1.0  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] colorspace_1.2-6 grid_3.1.1       gtable_0.2.0     munsell_0.4.3    plyr_1.8.3       Rcpp_0.12.6     
[7] scales_0.4.0     tools_3.1.1
```

## Graph preparation and export

```
a  <- ggplot(data = mtcars) +
  geom_point(aes(x = mpg, y = cyl))

b  <- ggplot(data = mtcars) +
  geom_line(aes(x = wt, y = vs))

# grid
gridAB  <- grid.arrange(a, b)
# Export
ggsave(filename="ab.pdf", plot=gridAB)
```

## Class

```
> class(gridAB)
[1] "gtable" "gTree"  "grob"   "gDesc"
```

---

## *Preview*

[image: Results]