# Left-align titles and subtitles with y-axis labels in ggplot2 graph in Shiny application

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, shiny

I built a Shiny application with multiple ggplot2 graphs of Social Security trust fund valuation metrics for a project. The plot titles are currently left-aligned with the left edge of the Cartesian coordinate plane. This doesn't fit our style guide.

In a static (non-Shiny) ggplot2 graph, I can use `theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = -0.24)` to align the title with the left edge of the y-axis labels. In the Shiny application, the y-axis labels change and the length can be $100, $1,000, $10,000, etc. depending upon selections in the application. Is there a way to left-justify titles and subtitles to the left edge of the longest y-axis label other than guessing-and-checking with `hjust = -x.x`?

**An example:**

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = "Diamonds",
       subtitle = "Bigger Dimaonds Cost More Money") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0)) +
  ylab(NULL) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0), labels = dollar) + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = -0.24),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = -0.57))
```

The title above is correctly aligned. Below, the length of the y-axis labels change and now the title is misaligned.

```
library(tidyverse)

diamonds %>%
  filter(price < 10000) %>%
  ggplot(aes(carat, price)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = "Diamonds",
       subtitle = "Bigger Dimaonds Cost More Money") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0)) +
  ylab(NULL) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0), labels = dollar) + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = -0.24),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = -0.58))
```

I found a lot of Stack Overflow posts from before ggplot2 2.2.0 when users wanted to left-align the title instead of using the default centered title. There is also a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25401111/left-adjust-title-in-ggplot2-or-absolute-position-for-ggtitle) for titles using `textGrob()` from grid and `arrangeGrob()` from gridExtra, but I have been unable to exapnd this solution to the subtitle.

I haven't found a solution to this problem. Also, I would have included informative images but I do not have 10 reputation. Thank you in advance!