# Set margins in ggplot2 individually

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a `ggplot2` style where the `title`, `subtitle` and the `axis.text.y` are all left aligned with 0 margin on the plot not on the y axis.

Then I want to have a different margin between the `axis.text.y` and the `panel.grid`, say 64px.

Can this be done in the `theme()` function?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)

iris %>%
  ggplot(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width,
             color = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = 0) +
  labs(title = "The Sepal.Width vs. Sepeal.Length",
       subtitle = "The iris dataset",
       y = "")
```

Desired outcome:

[image]

Comment: I guess it's is a duplicate to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25401111/left-adjust-title-in-ggplot2-or-absolute-position-for-ggtitle). You just need to use `y = NULL` instead of `y = ""`.

Comment: That doesn't work for the `title` and the `subtitle`

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47621310/1286528)

Comment: Why is this so complicated?

Comment: Is this a rhetorical question? I guess right now there's no easier solution to do that.