# ggplot - centre plot title with total width of image

Tags: r, ggplot2

The advice typically given to center a plot (or any element) is to use `hjust` along the lines of:

```
ggplot() +
  ggtitle("Use theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) to center") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

I've noticed however that in the case of a plot title, this centres it over the graphed variables, but not the entire width of the image. If there's a legend or the y-axis text is too long, they can push the plot area and title around.

The following three charts were exported with the same width and height. The first is the original, the second has a legend, and the third has larger y-axis text. The titles are the same font-size and have been centred using `hjust = 0.5`. While the charts take up the same amount of space, when stacked on top of each other, the titles do not align.
[image]
[image]
[image]

The code to repoduce:

```
data(mtcars)
mtcars$cyl = factor(mtcars$cyl)
mtcars$carb = factor(mtcars$carb)
require(dplyr)
averages_carb <- mtcars %>%
  group_by(carb) %>%
  summarise(mpg = mean(mpg))
averages_carb_cyl <- mtcars %>%
  group_by(carb, cyl) %>%
  summarise(mpg = mean(mpg))

png("No legend - regular y-text.png",width = 1000,height = 693, res = 120)
(graph <- ggplot(averages_carb, aes(x = carb, y = mpg)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 20),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10)) +
  ggtitle("No legend - regular y-text") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(1:25), labels = c("Low MPG", rep("", 23), "High MPG")))
dev.off()

png("Legend - regular y-text.png",width = 1000,height = 693, res = 120)
(graph_legend <- ggplot(averages_carb_cyl, aes(x= carb, y = mpg, fill = cyl)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 20),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10)) +
  ggtitle("Legend - regular y-text") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(1:28), labels = c("Low MPG", rep("", 26), "High MPG")))
dev.off()

png("No legend - large y-text.png",width = 1000,height = 693, res = 120)
(graph_large_text <- ggplot(averages_carb, aes(x = carb, y = mpg)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 20),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 20)) +
  ggtitle("No legend - large y-text") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(1:25), labels = c("Low MPG", rep("", 23), "High MPG")))
dev.off()
```

Comment: While this is stated well, it would be helpful to have a reproducible example with sample data. You can use the same dataset for both (shown different ways) or two different datasets, it doesn't matter. I suggest sets like `ggplot2::diamongs`, `mtcars`, or `iris` for consideration, though there are certainly many to choose from. (Using an already-available datasets simplifies your question here and our "playing" with the data.)

Comment: @r2evans thanks for the advice, I'll add it shortly

Comment: NicholasHassan, I suspect that any solution you find will be manipulating grobs, and sensitive to the rendered size of the plot. For example, create a ggplot object (`gg <- ggplot(...) + ...`). From here, you might be able to manipulate the grobs (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/q/25401111), but the relative width of individual components (legend, axes) changes based on the absolute width ... which is not known until `print(gg)`. So if it looks good on your screen, it might not be aligned properly elsewhere (pdf, docx).

Comment: Wow, that's a detailed reproducible example, nice job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, this is not possible without manually manipulating grobs, which will be a lot of tinkering. A simple workaround is to make a title "figure" and print it above the actual figure. The `gridExtra` package makes this easy (but see also `patchwork`). For instance,

```
## Start matter ------------------------------------------------------

library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

## Data --------------------------------------------------------------

data(mtcars)

mtcars <-
  mtcars %>%
  mutate_at(vars(cyl, carb), factor)

averages_carb <-
  mtcars %>%
  group_by(carb) %>%
  summarise(mpg = mean(mpg)) %>%
  ungroup()

averages_carb_cyl <-
  mtcars %>%
  group_by(carb, cyl) %>%
  summarise(mpg = mean(mpg)) %>%
  ungroup()

## Figure 1 ----------------------------------------------------------

fig_1_title <-
  ggplot() +
  ggtitle("No legend - regular y-text") +
  geom_point() +
  theme_void() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 20, hjust = .5))

fig_1_main <-
  averages_carb %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = carb, y = mpg)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(
    breaks = 1:25,
    labels = c("Low MPG", rep("", 23), "High MPG")) +
  theme_minimal()

png(
  "No legend - regular y-text.png",
  width = 1000, height = 693, res = 120
)

grid.arrange(
  fig_1_title, fig_1_main,
  ncol = 1, heights = c(1/20, 19/20)
)

dev.off()

## Figure 2 ---------------------------------------------------------

fig_2_title <-
  ggplot() +
  geom_point() +
  ggtitle("Legend - regular y-text") +
  theme_void() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 20, hjust = .5))

fig_2_main <-
  averages_carb_cyl %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = carb, y = mpg, fill = cyl)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  scale_y_continuous(
    breaks = 1:28,
    labels = c("Low MPG", rep("", 26), "High MPG")) +
  theme_minimal()

png(
  "Legend - regular y-text.png",
  width = 1000, height = 693, res = 120
)

grid.arrange(
  fig_2_title, fig_2_main,
  ncol = 1, heights = c(1/20, 19/20)
)

dev.off()

## END ---------------------------------------------------------------
```

[image]

[image]

(Yes, their centers are aligned.)

Comment: Thanks! I wish it was easier with just the ggplot package, but this seems like it will work for every situation I could need it for